# JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'accordion'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

It seems this issue is in several questions on here.  But none of the answers seem to work for me.

There aren't any other libraries being imported, these are the only 2.
I'm not even doing anything with it yet, just the code you see here causes the error.

```
<head>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#accordion").accordion();
    });
</script>
```

I've tried SEVERAL different so called "solutions", but they ALL give the same error.  I'm not sure what else to do to get this to work.

EDIT:
I managed to get it to not show an error by doing this

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#accordion").accordion();
    });
</script>

<div id="accordion">
    <h3>Header</h3>
    <div>Content</div>
</div>
```

But this doesn't work, it just shows the 'Header' and 'Content' text like normal

Comment: You should put the jQuery in the bundle not the script, and the bundle should likely be first/in head here.  THAT is a way OLD version of jQuery BTW  Use 1.11.1 or so if you need older browser use (IE6 etc.)

Comment: I swaped 'Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js' with the @Scripts.Render("/bundles/jquery")
It doesn't cause an error now with that, but it just doesn't work.

Comment: Are you saying that it no longer says "Object doesn't support property or method 'accordion'"? If so, then this question is solved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that your bundle is executing the core `jquery` file a second time, AFTER you have included `jquery-ui`.

Here's what's happening:

1) The jquery source file is executed. This defines the `jquery` object

2) The jquery-ui source file is executed. This attaches a number of functions to this already-existing`jquery` object.

3) Your bundle including the jquery source is executed. This redefines the `jquery` object, losing all of the functionality attached in step 2.

Make sure you include the `jquery-ui` library AFTER the jquery bundles.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I removed '<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>' And replaced it with the Bundle, but it still doesn't work, it just stops the error

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you get a `blah is defined` or `blah is unsupported` error, the first thing to check is that your javascript source addresses are valid.

In this case, your link to jquery ui is invalid.

Add this link instead:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.7.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: Still does not work.  Same error. I'll change the question to reflect what you have.  Good to know that though :)

Comment: Actually I just tested that in Internet Explorer, Chrome, and Fire Fox.  It's not working in any of them.

Comment: @MuzzyA That's because I was using an HTTP link rather than an HTTPS  link. It turns out that jsfiddle blocks those links on shares. (Something I've just learnt). Try this one: https://jsfiddle.net/dj2syv34/1/

Comment: I downloaded the jquery javascript files and added them to the project.  I updated the question to reflect what I have.  But it still gives the same error.  That second jsfiddle link worked for me btw :) but it doesn't help me :(